# A pure Javascript timer, similar to setInterval

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to repeat a function every 1 second, and I know that a very good too for that would be the `setInterval` function , but sadly I am running the script for a program, so it doesn't have the advantages of browser javascript functions (`setInterval()`, `setTimeout()`, `alert()`, basically all [window related functions](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window.asp))
So is it possible to execute a block of code , or a function that contains said code, every 1 second?

Please bear in mind I only recently have started writing code in Javascript and only have a basic understanding of it.

Comment: What do you mean by *donest have the advantages of browser javascript functions*?

Comment: your question is too vague to understand. what actually you want, `setInterval, setTimeout` okay, but what about `alert`?

Comment: @ArtursBuikis Are you using node.js?

Comment: When you aren't executing the Javascript in a web browser, then where are you executing it?

Comment: What environment are you running this script in?

Comment: I need to make a timer without those 2 functions , cause I am not running my script in a browser , those 3 examples were just to point out what kind of functions I dont have access to because - again - those are not builtin for pure javascript.

Comment: The javascript code that im writing will be used in a proxy based program , that is a .jar file. So when you launch the .jar it scans a specific folder for scripts , and if it finds any , it loads them.

Comment: @Qantas The script is not a jar file , its a .js file that is being loaded by a java application

Comment: @ArtursBuikis: are you using Nashorn or Rhino to run the JS file?

Comment: @ArtursBuikis, your question cannot accrurately be answered without information about your operating environment.  Very generically, you can use the ECMAScript Date object which returns time in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague but you seem to avoid clearing it up so i apologise if my answer is off, but it's the best i can do.

The way i would solve this is by changing the environment to allow the setTimeout/setInterval functions, similarly to how the browsers do it.

If that option is not available, you can go the route markE suggested in a comment: busy-wait until the date is the one you want, something along the lines of this::

```
var lastSecond = (new Date()).getSeconds();
while (true) {
  if (lastSecond !== (new Date()).getSeconds()) {
    lastSecond = (new Date()).getSeconds();
    console.log('Time is:', new Date());
  }
}
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/aNiRiZE/1/edit

Obviously the busy-waiting will block the thread that is running it, so i would strongly suggest the first solution of injecting implementations for setTimeout/setInterval in your environment.